# How to Display Show Attachment in Info Window

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using below code to display identifier popup.if I click on particular point it will display all the information about that point in info window(popup).but even if I specify show attachments true it will not display the attachments.In Map server I have an image for points.so I need to display info window as well as the image.

```
 map.on("load", mapReady);

        var parcelsURL = "MY MAP SERVER";
        //map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(parcelsURL,
        //  { opacity: 20 }));

        function mapReady() {
            map.on("click", executeIdentifyTask);
            //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
            identifyTask = new IdentifyTask(parcelsURL);

            identifyParams = new IdentifyParameters();
            identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
            identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
            identifyParams.layerIds = [0];
            identifyParams.layerOption = IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
            identifyParams.width = map.width;
            identifyParams.height = map.height;
        }

        function executeIdentifyTask(event) {
            identifyParams.geometry = event.mapPoint;
            identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

            var deferred = identifyTask
              .execute(identifyParams)
              .addCallback(function (response) {
                  // response is an array of identify result objects
                  // Let's return an array of features.
                  return arrayUtils.map(response, function (result) {
                      var feature = result.feature;
                      var layerName = result.layerName;

                      feature.attributes.layerName = layerName;
                      if (layerName === 'GridPoint') {
                          var popupTemplate = new PopupTemplate({
                              title: "",
                              fieldInfos: [
                                {
                                    fieldName: "XX",
                                    visible: true,
                                    label: "XX"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "YY",
                                    visible: true,
                                    label: "YY"

                                }
                              ],
                              showAttachments: true
                          });
                          //var taxParcelTemplate = new InfoTemplate("",
                          //  "XX: ${XX} <br/> YY: ${YY} <br/> Sample Point Number: ${Sample Point Number} <br/> Point Collected: ${Point Collected} <br/>  Major Rabi Crops: ${ Major Rabi Crops} <br/> Major Summer Crop: ${Major Summer Crop} <br/> Soil Type: ${Soil Type} <br/> Major Kharif Crops: ${Major Kharif Crops}");
                          feature.setInfoTemplate(popupTemplate);
                      }
                      //else if (layerName === 'Grid') {
                      //    console.log(feature.attributes.objectid);
                      //    var buildingFootprintTemplate = new InfoTemplate("",
                      //      "OBJECTID: ${OBJECTID}");
                      //    feature.setInfoTemplate(buildingFootprintTemplate);
                      //}

                      return feature;
                  });
              });

            map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
            map.infoWindow.show(event.mapPoint);
        }   
    });
someone please help me to display attachments(image) in info window.
```

Comment: The documentation for showAttachments states "When true, display attachments for feature layers that have attachments enabled".  How do you have attachments enabled for featurelayer?

Comment: Even though i am making show attachments true it will not display any attachments... what are the other ways to do this.

Comment: @Venkatesh Did you ever find a solution for this?